# Am I losing data since I'm not performing differential backups?

Tags: sql-server, backup

I have an OLTP production database (under 5gb) that gets a full back up every morning which is restored to a backup server.  Hourly tlogs are backed up and restored after that.

I have referenced the data on the restored backup and never noticed any issues or loss.

I was wondering, since differential backups are used to capture changes in data pages, is it possible I am missing data and just haven't noticed?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_backup "A differential backup is a type of data backup that preserves data, saving only the difference in the data since the last full backup." As long as you're really taking full backups, there's no need for differentials.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. I just needed confirmation for peace of mind :-)